# How to avoid edits rejected by community?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, rejected-edits

I edited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9226187). But this has been rejected by community saying

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

But i don't see the edit better than mine. This has not happened once, here are other Questions [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9062931) ,[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9062341) all my rejected 6 edits was rejected with same reason.I have two questions here.

1) Why is this happening even when edits suggestions were good?

2) How to avoid edits getting rejected by community?

I'm asking this because, sometimes i think that i'll stop suggesting edits because of this continuous rejection for no reason. I know there are no negative points for rejection but still i feel sad for getting rejected.

Though the edit was good, currently it is rejected and added to users rejected count.When it is getting conflicted, Will it be better if we have some other option like **conflicted** instead of **Rejected by Community**? and not getting added to the users rejected count?

Comment: You can't avoid it, there just isn't a safeguard preventing synchronous edits -- it's a UI defect.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you are editing a post in which is being edited by a user with over 2000 reputation. What happens is when you edit the question and it goes into the review queue, some user may edit the post before your edit is review. This will automatically make your edit become "rejected by community".

Most of the time the person who overwrote your edit never saw it, it just happens that you and another user are editing the question at about the same time. It is not rejected on purpose. Simply edit the question again if you can improve upon the most recent edit.

Comment: In that case won't it be better to have message or something called **conflicted** instead of **"rejected by community"**? Updated my question

Comment: @Crazy2crack: "rejected by community" must stay, because only a mod (like community) can insta-reject everything. And isn't the reason given - "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit" - good enough? Well, one might argue for a link to a post explaining that with more words... Also, those don't count against you...