# Rejected edit for edition of lower quality

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I found my edit to a question [to be anonymously rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9624320) with the explanation *«This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit»*.

I became curious of how better the another edit that it was preferred over mine, and found that [the accepted edit is in fact worse](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32767711/revisions) *(it is the first edition there; I couldn't give a direct link, because it for some reason doesn't show a difference)*. I.e. whilst mine edition preserved code formatting, the accepted edition removed the code indentation.

I wrote to the editor in comments, but they say that they didn't reject it *(the rejection is made anonymously)*. But actually there's very little possibility that someone else did it in such a close time; and I am really doubt that a user with high enough reputation to do it would try trolling us; and in the end the rejection was anonymous — that is too much to be just a coincidence.

How should I treat this?

Comment: Hm, so that is some kind of automatic system… I think it should be improved, because it shouldn't work as it is now. Okay, thank you, I'll ask a feature request.

Comment: You better search first for similar request. Keep in mind that 2K-ers have the privilege to edit posts. Their edits reject any edits in the queue.

Comment: @rene okay, I'll look at this. I should say, that I wouldn't want, after I get 2k reputation, that my edits would reject edits in queue. Just because it leads to peoples who would mistakenly think of me as of an impudent… guy. That's what I thought when I met this situation, when they perhaps didn't even knew it. It can not be the right system.

Comment: [Automatic rejections due to an editing conflict do not count against you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277900/4342498) so I don't see this as an actual issue.

Comment: It works for me and a lot of others. Make sure your feature request has enough new compelling reasons and arguments why this should change. The single bad experience you just had on its own isn't an argument to change the mechanics.

Comment: @rene no no, I am sure that it happens often. I didn't edit much posts, and I had two situations with rejection — and you know what? The previous time it was just fortunate that the edition was much better *(there was a grammar, whilst I'm not a native english speaker)*. See: it could happen — and I'm sure, it does often — that the edit would be the same as the rejected one. Ones who don't know that system, as I am, would think of the people as bastards, would hate them, and perhaps would even try to research the person *(e.g. hack their site)* to revenge — while the person really is innocent!

Comment: Well, I found a [feature-request addressing the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302883/2388257) indeed being already asked. Peoples doesn't seem to support it much, just nice…